# Untrack files from git, keep them in remote automatically deployed repository

Tags: git

There is a "blog" folder in the current git project that I want to remove from the git repository, but keep those files on the local and the remote server.

The remote server is set to automatically deploy the repo and I can not run any git commands on it other than the 'git pull' which it will automatically do after local push.

I need to stop tracking the blog folder, but need it to be preserved after the remote server does pull.

Seems simple but I could not find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you cannot do anything at your server except for `git pull` and you want to get rid of those blog files at some of the working directories (dev I believe), but not others (server). Is that correct?

Doesn't sound simple to me at all, more than that, doesn't sound like possible with the git's principles of functioning. IMHO.

You should get some access to the server once to copy the excluded blog files back to the blog directory. After that they will sit on the server only and will not be present at the later revisions of the repository.

If you do not have access to the server, the most you can do is add the blog files to the `.gitignore` so the local changes won't be ever pushed to the server.

Comment: I do not want to get rid of the files, I just want it out of the git repo/do not want them tracked in git anymore. Git should just continue tracking whatever is outside the blog folder.

Comment: That's correct. Copy the blog files somewhere at the server.  Remove the files from git repo 'git rm blog && git commit && git push', optionally 'echo blog >> .gitignore'. Do git pull at the server, blog files disappear. Copy them from where you had saved them before. Now blog files present server not tracked git.

Comment: The only problem is that I do not have access to the server.